# What is a substitute for logical operator || so an if statement doesn't always evaluate true

Tags: php

I have the following `if` statement that I want to evaluate, before I `unlink` the existing profile picture, but only if it's NOT the initial default profile pictures.

```
    //Checks to see if the unlink file is the default image on sign-up (if it is, don't delete)
    if($user['profile_pic'] != "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_black.png"
        || $user['profile_pic'] != "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_blue.png"
        || $user['profile_pic'] != "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_green.png"
        || $user['profile_pic'] != "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_red.png"
        || $user['profile_pic'] != "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_yellow.png"
        ){
        unlink($user['profile_pic']);
    }
    else{
        null;
    }
```

The problem I'm finding with the logical operator `||` is that even if one of these statements in true it's all true, but false only of they're all false.  The problem is, at least one of these will always be true and therefore `unlink` the default images from the folder.  The default images (of different color) are assigned randomly on registration.

What could I use other than `||` so that this evaluates as intended?

Comment: Hint: You want something that evaluates to true only if all of them are true.

Comment: && is the thing you are looking for

Comment: @HarshadShettigar Post answer as answer please.

Comment: `&&` ...hmmm.  I'll try it.  With `&&` all of them would be true.  In which case it would unlink the profile pic, which would NOT be the default.  smh

Answer (score 1):

change your operator from `!=` to `==` then swap the process

```
//Checks to see if the unlink file is the default image on sign-up (if it is, don't delete)
if($user['profile_pic'] == "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_black.png"
    || $user['profile_pic'] == "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_blue.png"
    || $user['profile_pic'] == "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_green.png"
    || $user['profile_pic'] == "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_red.png"
    || $user['profile_pic'] == "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_yellow.png"
    ){
     null;
}
else{
    unlink($user['profile_pic']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea to help remove some redundancy would be using a match:

```
<?php
# Match the path string and color
preg_match('!assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/prof_img_([^.]+)\.png$!', $user['profile_pic'], $match);
# If it doesn't require a match of only 'black','blue','green','red', or 'yellow', this may be fine to stop here with true/false
# if(empty($match[1]))
#     unlink($user['profile_pic']);
# If there are a possibility of more colors, you can match the found color to only your select few colors
$color  =   (!empty($match[1]))? $match[1] : false;
# If there is a possibilty of other colors and only these should be matched, then you can check from a list of colors here
if(!in_array($color, ['black','blue','green','red','yellow'])){
    # If not found, unlink
    unlink($user['profile_pic']);
}
```